# Generate CSR with 2 OU Names

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, openssl

I have to create an application which generates a CSR. While generating a CSR we are required to fill in several details like CN, OU, etc. The problem is that the Certifying Authority to which I have to send my CSR wants 2 OU(Organizational Unit) Names. I googled a lot but couldn't find anything using either openssl or java keytool by which I can specify 2 OU Names.

Can someone please tell me how I can specify 2 OU Names while generating the CSR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this easily with `openssl`:

```
openssl req -new -out myserver.csr \
  -newkey rsa:2048 -sha1 -nodes -keyout myserver.key  \
  -subj "/C=US/ST=New York/L=New York/O=My Company/OU=1st OU/OU=2nd OU/CN=www.myserver.net"
```

(If you already have a key you wish to use, omit `-newkey rsa:2048 -sha1 -nodes` and use `-key myserver.key` instead of `-keyout ...`)

You can inspect the CSR before you submit it with:

```
openssl req -in myserver.csr  -noout -text
```