# Own attributes openssl

Tags: certificates, openssl

Is there a way to include my own attributes into an openssl certificate?

e.g 
...
Country Name (2 letter code) [GB]:

State or Province Name (full name) [State]:

Locality Name (eg, city) [City]:

Organization Name (eg, company) [My Company Ltd]:

Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) [Section]:

Common Name (eg, your name or your server's hostname) []:

Extra Stuff (eg, dunno) []:

Extra Stuff2 (eg, dunno2) []:
.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There are two options: set this in the request and make sure it's preserved when signing (something a commercial CA will be disinclined to); or explicitly set during the signing.

The DN (distinguished name) is a single field in a request or certificate. It's an X.500 name, so it has one or more typed attribute/value pair components. This meaning of "attribute" isn't exactly the same as an "attribute" used in a request, [this part](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/req.html#DISTINGUISHED_NAME_AND_ATTRIBUTE) of the documentation explains some of the distinction.

(There is also a distinction between X.509 *attributes*, and *extensions*, here's my answer that shows how to go about [adding arbitrary extensions](https://serverfault.com/questions/581023/openssl-custom-extension) to a certificate when signing, which might be what you need if you want to add something that's not in the DN.)

If you want extra components in the subject name (DN) then it's easiest to [use the `-subj` option](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39525/generate-csr-with-2-ou-names) when generating the request, or when signing it. If the types are not already known to OpenSSL you can use OIDs directly, or add them via an `oid_file`, or `oid_section` in `openssl.cnf` .

Note however that the attributes that are widely supported in a DN are limited, see [RFC 5280 §4.1.2.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.4) (these are the constraints for the *Issuer* field, but §4.1.2.6 for the *Subject* field refers to this for its requirements).

If you want to be prompted for these during the normal `openssl req` process you can add them to either `[ req_distinguished_name ]` (where they will become part of the DN) or to `[ req_attributes ]` (where then will become an extra attribute in the request, which is probably less useful to you). There are some examples in the [`req` documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/req.html) and in the [extensions documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/x509v3_config.html).

Answer (score 1):

The fields you're listing are used to comprise the Subject, so I think you're asking what you're allowed to put into the [Subject](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.6) field.  The answer is, that's an x.501 Name, and there's all kinds of stuff you can put in there.  I'm no expert, but I think you can even make your own stuff up and put it in there if you encode it correctly and don't stomp on existing OIDs.

That being said, there's no guarantee your CA will actually keep anything you put in there when they sign your cert.  For example, [Startcom](http://cert.startcom.org/) strips out a number of Subject attributes such as O (Organization) and OU (Organizational Unit) before signing.  [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280) has a lot of discussion of what must be accepted, and how things that aren't required need to be tolerated, in a certificate.